# Renaming resources in Visual Studio does not update their references

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resources, visual-studio-designer

I have added some image files as resources to my project through the `Resources.resx`. But if I change the name of the image file after adding it, both in `Resources.resx` and in the "Resources" folder on the Solution Explorer window, Visual Studio does not update their references and instead flairs errors that the "old" resource is missing. I find it very odd and wonder if that is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename the resource property name, it's enough to open your `.resx` file in designer and then simply rename the entry. This way, visual studio renames the property everywhere it has been used.

To rename the file name, you have 2 options:

- After renaming it to new desired name, delete entry from `.resx` file and add/paste a file with the same new name to the `.resx` file.
- As another option, you can open `.resx` file using in code view (using <kbd>f7</kbd> or view code) and then find the entry and use new file name, then save file and close it. The entry is somwthing like this:

  ```
  <data name="SomeName" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\SomeName.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  ```

  as you can see, the file name is `SomeName.png` in `Resources` folder which can be replaced by a new file name.

Comment: I could swear when renaming it in .resx before it didn't do a thing, but now it did. :)